# How to match environment variable in logback.xml in spring

Tags: java, spring, logback

I am using `logback.xml` for logging purpose in my core spring application. It is working fine. But I want to apply condition based logging in my application.

I want to get environment variable and apply condition, and based on that, my logging should work.

```
<property name="profile" value="${spring.profiles.active}"/>
```

I am able to get variable value. But while I am trying

```
<if condition ='property("${profile}").equalsIgnoreCase("st")'>
    <then>
    </then>
</if
```

It is not working. I tried may different ways. How can I match the condition logback.